# ListView appearing only when attaching HierarchyViewer

Tags: android, hierarchyviewer

I have a `ListView` with a custom `Adapter` that extends `CursorAdapter`. The list is defined in such a layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/ProgressBar.Itasa.Indeterminate.Large"/>

    <net.italiansubs.droitasa.widget.HookedListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            style="@style/NewsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `HookedListView` looks like this:

```java
package net.italiansubs.droitasa.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ListView;
import net.italiansubs.droitasa.util.OnLayoutChangedListener;

/**
 * An extended ListView that has an hook for getting layout changes.
 *
 * @author Sebastiano Poggi, Francesco Pontillo
 */
public class HookedListView extends ListView {

    private OnLayoutChangedListener mLayoutListener;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mFirstLayout = true;

    public HookedListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    }

    public HookedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    }

    public HookedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if (mFirstLayout) {
            // In this case we want to avoid posting, because this could
            // have the two layout passes happen one after the other with
            // a pause between each other, with the effects, for example,
            // of having the number of columns change
            mFirstLayout = false;

            new LayoutChangedRunnable().run();
        }
        else if (changed) {
            mHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new LayoutChangedRunnable());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the OnLayoutChangedListener for this instance, that will
     * receive callbacks after layout changes for the View.
     *
     * @param l The new OnLayoutChangedListener, or null to remove
     *          the current listener.
     */
    public void setOnLayoutChangedListener(OnLayoutChangedListener l) {
        mLayoutListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the OnLayoutChangedListener set for this instance.
     *
     * @return Returns the instance's OnLayoutChangedListener, if any.
     */
    public OnLayoutChangedListener getOnLayoutChangedListener() {
        return mLayoutListener;
    }

    private class LayoutChangedRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // We don't need to synchronize on the listener because the handler
            // is hooked up to the main thread's looper so we shouldn't be
            // called from other threads.

            if (mLayoutListener != null) {
                mLayoutListener.onLayoutChanged(HookedListView.this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `ListView` contents don't appear on the device, even though the `Cursor` has items, the `Adapter` has items, and the `ListView` itself has items. Attaching the **HierarchyViewer** to the window does make the `ListView` items appear without any further intervention, and the same does requesting an update of the data from the webservice, which in turn updates the contents of the `ContentProvider`. I've tried setting up content observers for both the `Cursor` and the `Adapter`, and logging to ensure the correct number of items is set to the `Adapter`, and it's all working as intended. We already perform one extra layouting round on the List because of our custom `MultiCoumnAdapter`, that calculates the number of columns after the first `ListView` layout pass (thus the need for a `HookedListView`).

I've tried using a standard `CursorAdapter`, instead of my own `MultiColumnAdapter` (which emulates a `GridView`, without all its limitations and bugs), but this doesn't change anything.

The `Fragment` is the only content of an `Activity`; the `Activity` itself basically does nothing but getting an item ID from the extras of the `Intent` used to launch it, and passes it to the `Fragment`, which is defined in the `Activity`'s layout XML as the only element.

What the `Fragment` does is just handling getting the data from the app's `ContentProvider` using a standard `CursorLoader`. We use [DataDroid](http://www.datadroidlib.com) to manage getting new data from the webservice.

Is there anyone with the slightest clue on what's happening here? Seems like something gets stuck in the `ListView` own code until we update the underlying `Cursor`...

Comment: "Attaching the HierarchyViewer to the window does make the ListView items appear without any further intervention" -- do you mean that the list appears empty, then all of a sudden fills in when Hierarchy View loads the hierarchy? Have you tried temporarily switching to a regular `ListView`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I'm going to try with a regular `ListView` using Chris' suggestion as to avoid using that hooked `ListView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact you're messing with onLayout on ListView rings alarm bells. Why don't you just use a standard ListView with a [OnGlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)?

Or if you need the custom ListView, try changing your `onLayout()` to:

```
final LayoutChangedRunnable mLayoutRunnable = new LayoutChangedRunnable()

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    if (changed) {
        post(mLayoutRunnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was using that mechanism because I wasn't aware there was a global View tree observer... now that you mention it, I recall seeing it in the autocomplete sometime, but I also forgot about its existence. Now I'm going to get rid of that `HookedListView` and use the `OnGlobalLayoutListener`; I don't need any hook other than knowing when the `ListView has been attached, measured and laid out, to be able to determine the number of columns that will fit in the available space. I guess the global hook will do the trick! I'll let you know -- thanks!

Comment: Ok swapped out the `HookedListView` and switched to the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on a plain old `ListView` but the behaviour persists: no items are shown until the HierarchyViewer is attached or the underlying `Cursor` for the `Adapter` is updated (it's cleared and re-filled, since the data comes from the parsing of a web page)

Comment: Ok, after testing and tinkering, turns out calling:

        // Force a layout pass
        mListView.requestLayout();

at the end of the `Fragment`'s `onResume` does the trick. I'm still baffled by the how and why this absurd glitch happens, and I'd be delighted if someone with more insight than I do could explain it to me...

Comment: An update: I had found a workaround for this using the `onGlobalLayout` callback as suggested by @ChrisBanes (which triggers a relayout, just like the HierarchyViewer does), but now I'm facing the issue again after changing the list `Cursor`, both using `swapCursor` and creating a new `MulticolumnAdapter` (the `swapCursor` makes a mess if the list is scrolling, and I can't usa `changeCursor` because the `Cursor` comes from a `Loader`). This is driving me nuts! Seems like some weird drawing/compositing glitch... evertyhing is in order, the Adapter works, and a relayout makes it appear. Ideas?